Quitar <xsi:type="xsd:string"> en XML desde C#
Estoy intentando consumir un servicio SOAP desde C#.Net, hay un atributo en el WSDL definido como "objeto", pero no tengo forma de pasarlo correctamente.
Si importo System.Xml y creo el XML, al pasar XMLDoc.OuterString y analizar el XML que envío a SOAP, veo que agrega la propiedad xsi:type a la etiqueta XML y devuelve un error de validación.
Si uso un objeto y lo paso directamente me dice que no se pudo serializar correctamente. Si serializo el objeto y paso el XML como cadena, recibo nuevamente un error de validación.
//Todas las clases definidas vienen en el servicio.
scspwsClient p_servicio = new Client();
PeticionSincrona p_peticionSincrona = new PeticionSincrona();
Atributos p_atributos = new Atributos();
SolicitudTransmision[] p_SolicitudTransmision = new SolicitudTransmision[1];
DatosGenericos p_datosGenericos = new DatosGenericos();
Solicitante p_solicitante = new Solicitante();
Procedimiento p_procedimiento = new Procedimiento();
Funcionario p_funcionario = new Funcionario();
ItemsChoiceType[] p_itemsNameFuncionario = new ItemsChoiceType[2];
string[] p_itemsFuncionario = {"XXXXXXXXXXX" , "000000X" };

//credenciales
p_servicio.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = usuarioServicio;
p_servicio.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = passwordServicio;

//atributos servicio
p_atributos.CodigoCertificado = "XXXXXXXXXX";

//atributos body
p_solicitante.IdentificadorSolicitante = "XXXXXXXXX";
p_solicitante.NombreSolicitante = "XXXXXXXXX";
p_solicitante.UnidadTramitadora = "XXXXXXXXX";

p_procedimiento.CodProcedimiento = "XXXXXXXXX";
p_procedimiento.NombreProcedimiento = "XXXXXXXXX";
p_solicitante.Procedimiento = p_procedimiento;
            
p_solicitante.Finalidad = "XXXXXXXXX";
p_solicitante.Consentimiento = XXXXXXXXX;
        
p_solicitante.IdExpediente = "XXXXXXXXX";

p_datosGenericos.Solicitante = p_solicitante;
p_SolicitudTransmision[0] = new SolicitudTransmision();
p_SolicitudTransmision[0].DatosGenericos = p_datosGenericos;

p_peticionSincrona.Atributos = p_atributos;
p_peticionSincrona.Solicitudes = p_SolicitudTransmision;

//datosEspecificos

//datos específicos como XML
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode consultaNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Consulta");
XmlNode matriculaNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Matricula");
matriculaNode.InnerText = "XXXXXXXXX";
consultaNode.AppendChild(matriculaNode);
xmlDoc.AppendChild(consultaNode);


//datos específicos como objeto
//el objeto Consulta tiene solo el atributo matrícula
Consulta datosconsulta = new Consulta();
datosconsulta.Matricula = "XXXXXXXXX";

p_SolicitudTransmision[0].ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.DatosEspecificos;
p_SolicitudTransmision[0].Item = xmlDoc.OuterXml;

p_servicio.peticionSincrona(p_peticionSincrona);

//necesito eliminar el tipo xsd:string, porque al lanzar la petición desde SoapUI funciona sin el tipo.
Haciendo esto:

p_SolicitudTransmision[0].Item = xmlDoc.OuterXml;

me genera el XML así:
{...}
<DatosEspecificos xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns="http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/datosespecificos"></DatosEspecificos>
{...}

Y lo que me sobra es el atributo xsi:type="xsd:string"
Recibo este error por parte del servicio:
<detail>
<spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="http://springframework.org/spring-ws">UndeclaredPrefix: Cannot resolve 'xsd:string' as a QName: the prefix 'xsd' is not declared.</spring-ws:ValidationError>
<spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="http://springframework.org/spring-ws">cvc-elt.4.1: The value 'xsd:string' of attribute 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance,type' of element 'DatosEspecificos' is not a valid QName.</spring-ws:ValidationError>
<spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="http://springframework.org/spring-ws">UndeclaredPrefix: Cannot resolve 'xsd:string' as a QName: the prefix 'xsd' is not declared.</spring-ws:ValidationError>
<spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="http://springframework.org/spring-ws">cvc-attribute.3: The value 'xsd:string' of attribute 'xsi:type' on element 'DatosEspecificos' is not valid with respect to its type, 'QName'.</spring-ws:ValidationError>
</detail>


Puedes mostrarnos el código completo para reproducir el error o problema? No veo como puedes acabar con XML de name y gender si to C# utiliza CreateElement("Gender") y CreateElement("Name"). Y no has mostrado la creación de un elemento data que podría tener entonces un attributo xsi:type.

Gracias @MartinHonnen, he modificado la pregunta exactamente con mi código y no con un ejemplo. A ver si así puedes orientarme. gracias.

Finalmente añadí un MessageInspector para parar la petición antes de realizarla y modificar el XML. Quizá no sea la manera más limpia, pero sin tener acceso directo al schema y desconocer porqué genera el XML mal al asignar los atributos es complicado darle otra solución.

Finalmente añadí un MessageInspector para parar la petición antes de realizarla y modificar el XML. Quizá no sea la manera más limpia, pero sin tener acceso directo al schema y desconocer porqué genera el XML mal al asignar los atributos es complicado darle otra solución.
